# Implementing a universal Observer Pattern/Listener for the app

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

In my android app there's a lot of updates that need to be done after the lifecycle has been started and passed the initial states.
Right now I was working on adding an option to allow the user to disable receiving push notifications , and I had to create a custom "listener" so it would reach a method that's inside an onCreate callback, and I've noticed it is not the first time I'm doing this. 
So I was wondering, is there a way to make some "abstract" interface, instead of implementing a new listener for each class (there are dozens of them...).

Just for the sake of making myself more clear , here's a pseudo-code of what I mean:

```
interface X:
{
   void onDoneFragment1();
   void onDoneFragment2();
   void onDoneFragment3();
...
}
```

and then

```
fragment 1:
..
x.setOnListenFragment1( new OnDoneFragment1(){
@Override
public onDoneFragment1(){
......
..
```

same for fragment 2 and others..

```
 fragment 2:
    ..
    x.setOnListenFragment2( new OnDoneFragment2(){
    @Override
    public onDoneFragment2(){
    ......
    ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have two options:

1) Just make an abstract class with all blank impl. methods that way

2) If you use [RetroLambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) to add Java8 syntax support to Java7, and by relation to Android.... You can make [an Interface with 'default' methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).

Abstract class:

```
abstract class X:
{
   // having this makes sure the person only uses a method they have 'overridden'
   private Exception makeException(){
        return new Exception("Called Method from abstract class that wasn't overridden");
   }
   void onDoneFragment1(){throw makeException();}
   void onDoneFragment2(){throw makeException();}
   void onDoneFragment3(){throw makeException();}
...
}
```

Interface with 'default methods'

```
interface X:
{
   // having this makes sure the person only uses a method they have 'overridden'
   private Exception makeException(){
        return new Exception("Called Method from abstract class that wasn't overridden");
   }
   default void onDoneFragment1(){throw makeException();}
   default void onDoneFragment2(){throw makeException();}
   default void onDoneFragment3(){throw makeException();}
...
}
```

Comment: To add to this, the reason the exceptions are important is that way your new implementations/other classes don't end up calling a method that isn't "implemented" in your instance. That way you help prevent expected/unhandled callbacks